# Binding to ComboBox using ReactiveUI and Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, mvvm, binding, reactiveui

I would like to bind a property in my viewmodel to a ComboBox in a Windows Forms application, using ReactiveUI.

I found several examples with WPF but no examples with Windows Forms.

EDIT:
Part 1: Bind the selected value to 
Following example from comment:

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ViewModelProperty, v => v.comboBox.SelectedValue, comboBox.Events().SelectedValueChanged);
```

I get the error: `CS1955 Non-invocable member 'Component.Events' cannot be used like a method.`

Part 2: Bind the items in the ComboBox to a collection in the viewmodel
? Don't know how to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Observable.FromEventPattern` method to bind the firing of the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to your view model property.

```
comboBoxWithItems.DataSource = ViewModel.ListOfPossibleItemsProperty;
comboBoxWithItems.DisplayMember = "Name";

Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(
    ev => comboBoxWithItems.SelectedIndexChanged += ev,
    ev => comboBoxWithItems.SelectedIndexChanged -= ev)
    .Select(x => comboBoxWithItems.SelectedItem)
    .BindTo(this, x => x.ViewModel.SelectedItemProperty);
```

Answer (score 4):

First, your view should implement `IViewFor<YourViewModel>` interface and then

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.PropertyToBind, x => comboBox.SelectedValue, comboBox.Events().SelectedValueChanged)
```

**EDIT**: 
I have create a demo project:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IViewFor<MyViewModel>
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
            comboBox1.DataSource = ViewModel.Items;

            var selectionChanged = Observable.FromEvent<EventHandler, EventArgs>(
                h => (_, e) => h(e),
                ev => comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ev,
                ev => comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ev);
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.SelectedItem, x => x.comboBox1.SelectedItem, selectionChanged);
        }

        public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

        object IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get { return ViewModel; }
            set { ViewModel = (MyViewModel)value; }
        }
    }

    public class MyItem
    {
        private readonly string _text;

        public MyItem(string text)
        {
            _text = text;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _text;
        }
    }

    public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        private MyItem _selectedItem;

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ReactiveList<MyItem> {new MyItem("test1"), new MyItem("test2")};
        }

        public MyItem SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selectedItem, value); }
        }

        public ReactiveList<MyItem> Items { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I get an error when I try to do that... What am I missing? (see updated question)

Comment: `Install-Package reactiveui-events-winforms` ;)

Comment: Thanks again, but this package doesn't seem to be part of ReactiveUI... I can only use packages that are maintained by the core team. Any idea how to do that using the packages that the core team publishes?

Comment: If you don't want to use *reactiveui-events-winforms* package, you can replace  `comboBox.Events().SelectedValueChanged` with 
`Observable.FromEvent<EventHandler, EventArgs>(
                ev => comboBox.SelectedValueChanged += ev,
                ev => comboBox.SelectedValueChanged += ev);`

Comment: +1 Thank you. This seems to work when I change the selection (the binding happens) but when the application starts the binding doesn't happen and the combo box is empty (instead of selecting the first item). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial vm.SelectedItem is null and there is no change yet to update the VM from the view.
Set an initial selection in the VM constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas for improvement relating to the list of values:

1. Replace the direct set of `comboBox1.DataSource = ViewModel.Items;` with a bind `OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Items, v => v.comboBox1.DataSource);` so that it isn't necessary for `ViewModel` to exist inside the view constructor and `ViewModel` can be dynamically changed.
2. Use `ReactiveBindingList` instead of `ReactiveList` so that WinForms binding can react to changes in the value list (though I haven't tried this for this exact scenario).

Answer (score 0):

Since the other solutions did not work for me in UWP applications, there is a proper way that works in WinForms, WPF and UWP applications: use the `Bind` methods in the constructor of the view. Example for WPF/UWP:

```cs
using ReactiveUI;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;

    public sealed partial class MyView : Page, IViewFor<MyViewModel>
    {

        public MyView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WhenActivated(d =>
            {
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Items, v => v.DropDownControl.ItemsSource)
                    .DisposeWith(d);

                this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.SelectedItem, v => v.DropDownControl.SelectedItem)
                    .DisposeWith(d);
            });
        }


        public MyViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get => DataContext as MyViewModel;
            set => DataContext = value;
        }

        object IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get => ViewModel;
            set => ViewModel = value as MyViewModel;
        }
    }
```

In ViewModel:

```cs
using ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers;

    public sealed class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public void MyViewModel()
        {
            // Todo: Load items
        }

        [Reactive] public IList<MyItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<MyItem>();
        [Reactive] public MyItem? SelectedItem { get; set; }
    }
```